# Xcode 5 iOS 7 Simulator not loading Storyboard and making me crazy! (no Localization)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

After searching stackOverflow for almost an hour, I've come up empty and so I need your help please.

I have an master-detail project I created in Xcode 5 just a few days ago for iOS 7.

After finishing a large edit I launched the application and everything was working fine. Then I made a small change in the storyboard to a TableViewCell by changing the accessory from Checkmark to None.

When I ran the application again in the simulator the checkmarks were no longer there, but clicking on the Master view cells no longer loaded the detail view.

I found lots of people talking about this on stackOverflow, but all of them seem to have been trying to work with localization. I haven't touched localization, so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem I'm encountering.

Here's what I've tried without success:

- Changing the accessory setting back to Checkmark (checkmarks did not reappear in simulator)
- Double checking that "localization locking" is set to "Nothing"
- Clean Code (don't know what that does exactly, but I tried it...)
- Deleting and reinstalling the app from my simulator
- Quitting and reopening Xcode
- Removing the reference to the storyboard in the Project Navigator, rebuilding and running, then adding the storyboard back in (The app ran exactly the same without the storyboard in the project as it did with the storyboard)
- Restarting my computer
- Deleting the relevant Iphone Simulator directory in 'Users/Library/Application Support/Iphone Simulator' and then relaunching the simulator

None of these have worked!

The first page of the app shows up, but none of the storyboard functionality is working (no segues, no checkmarks).

I've been working on the assumption that its an issue with the background processes of Xcode, but it could very well be my code.

This is code from the MasterViewController.m file (It's the last thing I edited besides the Main.storyboard file where I set the TableCell accessory to 'None'):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = _cellStringsArray[indexPath.row];
//    if (!([cell.textLabel.text  isEqual: @"To Station"]||[cell.textLabel.text  isEqual: @"From Station"])) {
//        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
//    }
    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"preparing for segue to station selector");
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"search"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        THStationSearchViewController *searchview = [segue destinationViewController];
        searchview.stationSelection = indexPath.row;
        searchview.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

I'm super new to Xcode development, and also a programming noob in general. Am I just being an idiot? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Please save me and future people to encounter this issue from Xcode doom! I will be eternally grateful...

Comment: Post the relevant code so we can get a better idea? Chances are you missed something small.

Comment: Thanks Josue. Just added what I think is the most relevant piece of the code. Let me know if there are any other parts of the code that would be useful.

Comment: Why are your using `[[UITableViewCell alloc] init]` instead of `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`?

Comment: Thank you Jeffery!! That is why my code wasn't working... I took dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: because I knew I would create only 2 cells maximum in that TableView. Can anyone explain why you need to dequeue reusable cells if you don't have more than one View's worth of cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is you are using `[[UITableViewCell alloc] init]`. This creates a generic UITableViewCell with all default properties. You need to use `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` to create cells with all the custom properties you need.

The reason you want the table view to create new cells is that the table view knows how to create cells based on the prototype cell laid-out in the storyboard.

Hidden during the load of the table view from the storyboard are calls to `-registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` for all prototype cells defined in the table view. This tells the table view how to create a cell which looks like the prototype.

Comment: Awesome! That makes a lot of sense to me. dequeueReusable... is going through the process of registering the specific cells I created in the storyboard, not just create a new generic cell object like alloc-init does. Thanks for the full explination